# Different speed of generator to list conversion

Tags: python, list, generator

### Problem

So I wrote a python function which flattens a list by recursively yielding all elements of the nested lists. I came up with 2 different versions of the generator creating function (not 100% the same).

Here are the two versions:

```
def iterflatten_v1(lst):
    for x in lst:
        if isinstance(x, (list, tuple)):
            yield from iterflatten_v1(x)
        else:
            yield x

def flatten_v1(lst):
    return list(iterflatten_v1(lst))
```

```
def iterflatten_v2(lst):
    for x in lst:
        try:
            yield from iterflatten_v2(x)
        except TypeError:
            yield x

def flatten_v2(lst):
    return list(iterflatten_v2(lst))
```

Then I tested the speed ([timing function](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/)) for both of these functions with the following code:

```
import time

def timing(f, a, n):
    print(f.__name__)
    r = range(n)
    t1 = time.clock()
    for i in r:
        f(a); f(a); f(a); f(a); f(a); f(a); f(a); f(a); f(a); f(a)
    t2 = time.clock()
    print(round(t2-t1, 3))

nested = [1, 1, 1, [1, 1, [1, 1, 1, [1, 1, 1, 1, [1, 1, 1, 1], 1, 1], 1, 1], 1], 1]
data = [nested for i in range(1000)]

timing(iterflatten_v1, data, 1000)  # 0.003
timing(iterflatten_v2, data, 1000)  # 0.003
timing(flatten_v1, data, 10)  # 1.647
timing(flatten_v2, data, 10)  # 3.005
```

### Question

Why is the conversion for the `iterflatten_v1` generator almost twice as fast as the conversion for the `iterflatten_v2` generator, even though the generator functions have the same speed?

Comment: Because you're handling a lot more exceptions in v2 (one exception per leaf value), which all add up to more overhead.

Comment: v2 will also convert strings to lists of characters, which may be rather unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @deceze But wouldn't the overhead of v2 show up in its timing? Or are generators calculated while I am iterating through them?

Comment: This reminds me of the typical *"forgiveness vs. permission"* dilemma. To this end, you might find [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/175655/python-forgiveness-vs-permission-and-duck-typing) quite interesting

Comment: I don't understand. I thought you said v1 is twice as fast as v2…!?

Comment: That's true, but the generator functions have the same speed (speeds are in the comments of the timing function).

Comment: Well, yes, the generator doesn't do anything unless and until you iterate it.

Comment: Ok thanks. I got a little bit confused by that.

Comment: BTW sincere congratulations on the [mcve]. If all questions were like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as said in comments, exception handling consumes more memory than testing the type instance in this case.

However you were right to time both, and timing may vary depending on the data (if the data contains only integers, you'll get the exception more often, and the v2 will be even slower than it was compared to v1)

Note that if you don't have children of `tuple` or `list` you can get a 50% speedup by *not* using `isinstance` (which checks for base class), and check the exact type:

```
def iterflatten_v1(lst):
    for x in lst:
        if type(x) in (list, tuple):
            yield from iterflatten_v1(x)
        else:
            yield x
```

on my machine, I get 1,5s with the `isinstance` version, and less than 1 second with this version.

(and yes, I tested `isinstance(x,collections.Sequence)` and was very disappointed because it was even slower than testing 2 types)